# Angular routing - routing to a lazy module child path does not initiate the component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, lazy-loading

In my app-routing.module I have a lazy module:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'profile/:id',
        loadChildren: './profile/profile-standalone/profile-standalone.module#ProfileStandaloneModule',
    }
];
```

Here is my profile--standalone-routing.module-

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ProfileStandaloneComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'outputa',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'outputa',
                component: ProfileOutputComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProfileStandaloneRoutingModule { }
```

But when I go to url "localhost:4200/profile/123/outputa", my "ProfileOutputComponent" does not get called.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Since, both the router are redirecting to the same state, angular will take the first route who ever is received first and you even made path match "full" which will satisfy the first state too. Try changing your route structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'outputa',
    component: ProfileOutputComponent
];
```

Comment: ohh, We cannot put the children for the parent route `path = ''` because we cannot have `child route` for those parents who does not have any name. So, better provide some name for the path and then only the above solution will work.

Comment: but it does not work even when I delete the "path:''" and leaves only "outputa"

Comment: Is this working for you 'localhost:4200/profile/123/'?

Comment: Is this your folder name '/profile/profile-standalone/'? Try the latest edit.

Comment: yes, the feature module is in profile/profile-standalone. ProfileOutputComponent is in a different directory.

Comment: in this way- const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'outputa',
    component: ProfileOutputComponent
]; it works.. but this deos not give me the expected behavior

Comment: Can you please explain what is the expectation?

Comment: I found the problem! I forgot to include "<router-outlet></router-outlet>" in my component! thanks!

Comment: Great. Welcome.